# Do loop runs one too many times

Tags: excel, vba

So im trying to create a macro in VBA that finds a header e.g. Product number, then pastes all the product numbers and products (the adjacent column) in another workbook (Bill) in the format,

product number - product

until it reaches two blank cells. The problem is the loop runs one too many times and then pastes all the rows followed by "Error" and the red cell because both cells are blank. I've omitted a lot of lines for conciseness, but if it helps im happy to post the rest of it. Ive tried multiple things but just cant fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Bill.xlsx").Worksheets("Bill")

    Lastrow = wsDest.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Row

         Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 1))

         Set ANextFreeCell = wsDest.Cells(Lastrow, "L")

            If IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, j)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, j + 2)) Then
            ANextFreeCell = "Error"
            ANextFreeCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)

            Else
            ANextFreeCell = Cells(i + 1, j) & " - " & Cells(i + 1, j + 2)
            End If

            i = i + 1
            Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
            Loop
```

Comment: What is the `j` variable?

Comment: @Dominique so it starts by finding a particular word and then i is the row number of the word and j is the column number of the same word, so that product numbers and products can be found relative to one word

Comment: You didn't initialize i & j before entering the loop or it's just not shown.

Comment: @RetiredGeek I said in my question that i omitted a lot of lines for conciseness, and that the code actually works just runs one too many times

Comment: Maybe try `If Application.CountA(Range(Cells(i + 1, j), Cells(i + 1, j + 2))) = 1 Then` instead of `If IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, j)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, j + 2)) Then`